# XSLT insert element between copied section

Tags: xml, xslt-1.0

I am pretty new to xslt.
I am using xslt 1.0.
I have an xml document that has a undetermined structure and varies with each section :

```
<section label="">
 <subsection label="">
  <para label="">
   <subpara label=""></subpara>
   <subpara label=""></subpara>
  </para>
 </subsection>
</section>
<section label="">
 <subsection label="">

 </subsection>
</section>
<section label="">
 <subsection label="">
   <para label="">

   </para>
 </subsection>
</section>
```

I then traverse in a loop through each section building a string with the value of each node label, and then use a recursive method to copy each section nodes, child nodes with attributes and text.

```
 <xsl:template match="/">
 <xsl:for-each select="//section">
   <xsl:variable name="section">
     <xsl:value-of select="@label"/>
   </xsl:variable>
      <xsl:if test=".//subSection">
        <xsl:for-each select=".//subSection">
          <xsl:variable name="subsection">
            <xsl:if test="string-length(./@label) > '0'">
              (<xsl:value-of select="@label"/>)
            </xsl:if>
          </xsl:variable>

          <xsl:if test=".//para">
            <xsl:for-each select=".//para">
              <xsl:variable name="para">
                <xsl:if test="string-length(./@label) > '0'">
                  (<xsl:value-of select="@label"/>)
                </xsl:if>
              </xsl:variable>

              <xsl:if test=".//subPara">
                <xsl:for-each select=".//subPara">
                  <xsl:variable name="subpara">
                    <xsl:if test="string-length(./@label) > '0'">
                      (<xsl:value-of select="@label"/>)
                    </xsl:if>
                  </xsl:variable>
                  <xsl:if test=".//item">
                    <xsl:for-each select=".//item">
                      <xsl:variable name="item">
                        <xsl:if test="string-length(./@label) > '0'">
                          (<xsl:value-of select="@label"/>)
                        </xsl:if>
                      </xsl:variable>
                      <xmlstringtobuild name="{concat('XML_',$act,' s ',$section,$subsection,$para,$subpara,$item)}"/>
                    </xsl:for-each>
                  </xsl:if>
                  <xmlstringtobuild name="{concat('XML_',$act,' s ',$section,$subsection,$para,$subpara)}"/>
                </xsl:for-each>
              </xsl:if>
              <xmlstringtobuild name="{concat('XML_',$act,' s       ',$section,$subsection,$para)}"/>
            </xsl:for-each>
          </xsl:if>
          <xsl:if test="string-length(@label) > '0'">
            <xmlstringtobuild name="{concat('XML_',$act,' s ',$section,$subsection)}"/>
          </xsl:if>
        </xsl:for-each>
      </xsl:if>
      <xmlstringtobuild name="{concat('XML_',$act,' s ',$section)}"/>
      <xsl:call-template name="LNRecurseToRoot">
        <xsl:with-param name="parent" select="parent::*"/>
        <xsl:with-param name="current">
          <xsl:apply-templates select="." mode="lmt"/>
        </xsl:with-param>
      </xsl:call-template>
 </xsl:for-each>
</xsl:template>

<xsl:template name="LNRecurseToRoot">
<xsl:param name="parent"/>
<xsl:param name="current"/>
<xsl:choose>
  <xsl:when test="not($parent)">
    <xsl:copy-of select="$current"/>
   </xsl:when>
  <xsl:otherwise>
    <xsl:call-template name="LNRecurseToRoot">
      <xsl:with-param name="parent" select="$parent/parent::*"/>
      <xsl:with-param name="current">
        <xsl:for-each select="$parent">
            <xsl:copy>
            <!-- make sure all attributes go across too -->
            <xsl:for-each select="./@*">
              <xsl:copy/>
            </xsl:for-each>
            <!-- add in children along the axis -->
            <xsl:copy-of select="$current"/>
          </xsl:copy>
        </xsl:for-each>
      </xsl:with-param>
    </xsl:call-template>
  </xsl:otherwise>
</xsl:choose>
</xsl:template>
```

My problem is i would like to insert xmlstringtobuild element at the right place within the recursive copy output. (The end node where that string was built so that the specific string could be used as a pointer to the specific section, subsection, para, etc.). You could think of it as an internal link or anchor.

I could email someone dummy data of  the output i currently get.
Your help would be greatly appreciated. Thanks.

Comment: STOP CRYING, lowercase is quite better in titles. POST edited.

Comment: @sputnick sorry about that.

Comment: Hi Guys, is the question unclear in anyway, please let me know. Thanks.